Numpy/torch: Reindexing batch of vectors by batch of indexes
In numpy/torch -  for vector v and another vector of indices  we can reindex :
v[IX] 

How to do the same when I have batch of vectors v and batch of indexes ?
I mean v - is 2d array of v[i,:] - i-th vector, it should be reindexed by IX[i,:].
Slow Python way is just:
for i in range(v.shape[0]):
    new_v[i,:] = v[i,:][IX[i,:]]

But the question is to do it in numpy/torch way - without slow Python loops.
The idea comes to mind something like - v.ravel()[ (IX + range(v.shape[0) ).ravel() ].reshape(N,-1),
but may be there is more canonical/readable  way ?

Edit (solution found):
ChatGPT managed that, cannot believe.
import numpy as np

# Input arrays
v = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]])
IX = np.array([[2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]])

# Number of rows
num_rows = v.shape[0]

# Create an array of row indices
row_indices = np.arange(num_rows)[:, np.newaxis]

# Use advanced indexing to create new_v
new_v = v[row_indices, IX]

print(new_v)


The readable way is using np.take_along_axis:
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(34)

H, W = 300, 400

v = np.random.randint(0, 10, (H, W))
idxs = np.array([np.random.permutation(W) for _ in range(H)])

def reorder(v, idxs):
    v1 = np.zeros_like(v)
    for i in range(v.shape[0]):
        v1[i, :] = v[i, :][idxs[i, :]]
    return v1

v1 = reorder(v, idxs)
v2 = v[np.arange(H)[:, None], idxs]
v3 = np.take_along_axis(v, idxs, axis=1)

assert np.all(v1 == v2)
assert np.all(v2 == v3)

It is not faster though:
>>> %timeit reorder(v, idxs)
>>> %timeit v[np.arange(H)[:, None], idxs]
>>> %timeit np.take_along_axis(v, idxs, axis=1)
490 µs ± 419 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
414 µs ± 418 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
418 µs ± 537 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)


Thanks , upvoted. Though, question is how to avoid Python loop, just numpy

There is no python loop in my answer though: v3 = np.take_along_axis(v, idxs, axis=1)

Btw I also proposed v2 = v[np.arange(H)[:, None], idxs] which is the same as what you said ChatGPT found in your edit, but is less readable imho.

Sorry then, misread your proposal .
